# How to update key's value in existing json

Tags: python, json

Input json : `{"TX1":{ "EMR": "XSHGJ", "ID": "200", "SERIAL": "ZZZ001"},"TX2":{"EMR": "POIUY",   "ID": "300",   "SERIAL": "YYY001"}}`

I want to update key's value in Json, but when I'm trying to do it using below, its just adding new `key-value` at end of json

```
import json

stringJson = '{"TX1":{"EMR":"XSHGJ","ID":"200"},"TX2":{"EMR":"POIUY","ID":"300"}}'
# convert string to  object
json_object = json.loads(stringJson)

json_object["EMR"] = 'CHANGED'

print(json.dumps(json_object, indent = 1))
```

`

Getting output

`{ "TX1": { "EMR": "XSHGJ", "ID": "200", "SERIAL": "ZZZ001" }, "TX2": { "EMR": "POIUY", "ID": "300", "SERIAL": "YYY001" }, "EMR": "CHANGED" }`

but need output like

`{ "TX1": { "EMR": "CHANGED", "ID": "200", "SERIAL": "ZZZ001" }, "TX2": { "EMR": "CHANGED", "ID": "300", "SERIAL": "YYY001" } }`

May I know please, how can I Achieve this ?

Comment: Your JSON object is nested... You need to do json_object["TX1"]["EMR"]

Comment: Something like: `for value in json_object.values(): value['EMR'] = 'CHANGED'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate over the values, check if the value (assumed to be a dictionary) contains 'EMR' then update accordingly:

```
import json

stringJson = '{"TX1":{"EMR":"XSHGJ","ID":"200"},"TX2":{"EMR":"POIUY","ID":"300"}}'

d = json.loads(stringJson)

for v in d.values():
    if 'EMR' in v:
        v['EMR'] = 'CHANGED'

print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "TX1": {
    "EMR": "CHANGED",
    "ID": "200"
  },
  "TX2": {
    "EMR": "CHANGED",
    "ID": "300"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to change EMR key for all the root level keys. Like @Gugu72 said, the EMR key is nested so you need to run for loop for this

```
for key in json_object:
    if "EMR" in json_object[key]:
        json_object[key]["EMR"] = "CHANGED"
```

And now you can print the updated json object

```
print(json.dumps(json_object, indent = 1))
```

[image]